# Sonar: File not found, Resource not found, Class not found

Tags: java, gradle, sonarqube, jacoco

We recently implemented sonar to our projects.

So far, I can see the reports being generated on the Sonar dashboard but when I checked the logs, I can see "File not found", or "Class not found", or "Resource not found" of all the resources I use within the project.

I found the same sort of questions over the internet but their reports are not reflected on Sonar.

Any answer would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You should share analysis logs, details on the product versions you're using (SonarQube, scanner, plugins), and how your project is built.

Comment: We build the project using gradle and sonar gradle plugin 2.0.1. We are also using JacocoTestReport. The logs just says it cannot find all the classes we have on the project excluding the dependencies. I can also see "Coverage information was not collected. Perhaps you forget to include debug information into compiled classes?"

Comment: I can also see this message on the logs. *Coverage information was not collected. Perhaps you forget to include debug information into compiled classes?*